# Adding smart thermostat (nest) to burnham series 2 boiler

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, nest

[image][image][image][image]I’m trying to add a nest thermostat to my burnham series 2 boiler with two zones. My original thermostat has a red and white wire going to W and R with a jumper from R to RC. See first photo.

Where can I tap into my current system to locate the C wire? I also have one of those power adapters if need be.

Comment: C might be that connector in the top left of the green board, thunt one of the thermostats on and measure the AC voltage from that terminal to the thermostat terminals. (you should see about 24V)    the burnam photo is to blurry.for me to try to read it.

Comment: Can you post the make/model of your zone board please?

Comment: I won’t be back over there for a couple days but I’ll get the info when I’m there next! Thanks for the help, in advance!

Comment: I believe it’s a Taco SR 502. 

I was reading that I need to add a resistor between the 24VAC to the “W” ??

Comment: Correction, it’s an SR 503